# Issue multiple background image in css( 3images)

Tags: css

i have added three images to the background of the body of my website .two of them works fine (one of then is repeat-y but the third one doesnt seem to work.Trie alot search but found nothing
http://ixia.x90x.net/urdu.php

```
 body 
{
    background-image:     url(../_images/urdulower.png),   url(../_images/urduhead.png) ,   url(../_images/urdurepeating.png);
    background-position:  left bottom,                     left top,                        left 118px;
    background-repeat:    no-repeat,                       no-repeat,                       repeat-y;
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
z-index:20;
```

The highest value will be in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works. However, your repeating image (http://ixia.x90x.net/_assets/_images/urdurepeating.png) is not transparent and hence covers the bottom image.

Comment: the repeatin image is in thrid place .Giving specific width and absolute position to the #urducolumn makes all the problem.I have removed these values .it works fine then. http://ixia.x90x.net/urdu.php